# OurSQL Calling Procedure yields no results

Tags: python, mysql

In Python(2.7.3), I call a procedure using OurSQL(0.9.2)'s cursor.execute. However when I try to grab results using cursor.nextset() or cursor.fetchone() I get the error "oursql.ProgrammingError: (None, 'no results available', None)."

What I find really odd though is that the cursor.rowcount is not 0.

My Python code looks like this:

```
import oursql

conn = oursql.connect(host='www.example.com', user='foo', passwd='bar', port=3306)
curs = conn.cursor()

curs.execute("CALL db.foo(?, ?, ?)", (1, 2, 3))
print("Row count: " + str(curs.rowcount))
print(curs.nextset())
res = curs.fetchone()
print(res)
curs.close()
```

Here's the output:

```
Row count: 189
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(curs.nextset())
  File "cursor.pyx", line 169, in oursql.Cursor.nextset (oursqlx/oursql.c:16436)
  File "cursor.pyx", line 161, in oursql.Cursor._check_statements (oursqlx/oursql.c:16392)
oursql.ProgrammingError: (None, 'no results available', None)
```

As you can see it's telling me there are "no results available" however the row count is "189."

Am I doing something wrong here? I should mention that this same query gives me the same row count when I test it in MySQL Workbench and it does yield results.

Comment: This looks like a bug so I reported this to OurSQL's launchpad.
Check out [link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/oursql/+bug/1004991)